# How to parse .txt file and get data from it in swift 3

Tags: swift3, text-parsing

I have a text file, I want to parse the data from it, I want some data from that text file as, city name, max temp, year, 
here is link of text file [enter link description here](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/pub/data/weather/uk/climate/datasets/Tmax/ranked/UK.txt)
I want uk, max temp, year, and temp from this url. How can i parse it and get data from this text file. e.g, UK,Max temp,1910,JAN,5.4. Is this possible to parse and get data from this text file?
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't the service provide a more reasonable data format (e.g. JSON)?

Comment: no they dont provide yet any json file only gave text file

Comment: @vadian yes, they are providing, but he needs APIKey for it. Look at my edit.

Comment: The API key seems to be free. So it would be much more convenient than parsing this huge txt file.

Comment: ok thanks guys let me check

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3.0 you can parse txt file like this:

```
let file = "file.txt" //this is the file. we will write to and read from it

let text = "some text" //just a text

if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

    let path = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)

    //writing
    do {
        try text.write(to: path, atomically: false, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    }
    catch {/* error handling here */}

    //reading
    do {
        let text2 = try String(contentsOf: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    }
    catch {/* error handling here */}
}
```

Note: if you want to read some static data, my recommendation would always be a **JSON** file saved locally.

***EDIT:***

One more way, maybe easier approach:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("FileName", ofType: "txt")
var text = String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!
println(text)
```

EDIT:

[This is API example for your need in JSON](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/datapoint/support/api-reference)

Comment: ok @Stefan but how i parse some words or say numbers from this i am getting whole text document now

Comment: What is the example? How data is separated from other words?

Comment: e.g from above url i want UK,Maximum Temperature,1910,JAN,5.4; UK, Maximum Temperature,Feb,6.7 ; ..... like this

Comment: I don't see any symmetry here from which you will create an pattern to parse data.

Comment: then other way to get this kind data? from this url

Comment: As I said, JSON format is nicer for parsing. Maybe this site has it's own API to get it in JSON[key-value] format.